# Exported functions are not defined. Parcel/Browserify

Tags: javascript, module, export, browserify, parcel

When I use a bundler to make my JS browser compatible my exported functions are not exported.

Error: **(index):11 Uncaught TypeError: connect is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):11:46)**

index.js (Same root file as index.html)

```
const {ethers} = require("ethers");

async function connect() {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
        await ethereum.request({method: "eth_requestAccounts"});
      }
  }

  module.exports = {
    connect
  }
```

index.html (Same root file as index.js)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <script src="./index.js" type="module"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="connect" onclick="connect()">   Connect  </button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Using parcel, which auto creates a dist file and starts a local server.
Also tried browserify and had same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Parcel supports script tag/elements of type module.

This code works for me but window.ethereum is undefined, it's related to MetaMask no?

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="connect">Connect</button>

    <script type="module">
      //Import your module
      import something from "./index.js";

      //Assign event listener to button
      document
        .getElementById("connect")
        .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
          something.connect();
        });
      console.log("something", something);
      /* JavaScript module code here */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### index.js

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function connect() {
  console.log("Inside connect function");
  console.log("window.etherum", window.ethereum);
  console.log("ethers", ethers);
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== "undefined") {
    await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  connect,
};
```